# How do I represent this with best practice divs?

Tags: html, css

I have this table in our front end and I've been reading that DIV is the better way to code this, how would you represent the same structure in DIVs ?

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="title"><strong>Choose Dates</strong></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title"><strong>Search by Name</strong></td>
            <td class="title"><strong>Status</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><input type="text" id="dateFrom" /></td>
            <td><strong>To</strong></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="dateTo" /></td>

            <td><input type="checkbox"id="pendResCheckID" />Pending</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"id="ConfResCheckID" />Confirmed</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"id="CancResCheckID" />Canceled</td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like tabular data, where a table is correct.

Comment: @GrantThomas I don't see any tabular data there! It is just a form, and shouldn't be styled using `table`

Comment: or you need to use a grid system like the [bootstrap grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Well at this point I think it's still debatable - all these fields could be ready only, and tabular forms can be tabulur. Indeed, SO did this for a long time, at the behest of the community, don't even know if they changed it yet

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek you're correct, this is a Filter form used to filter data shown later on the page

Comment: The first row doesn't match the second (9 cols vs 7 cols), are you sure this is your current HTML?

Comment: @GrantThomas - There is no data there whatsoever so it can't be called 'tabular data'.

Comment: @Rob - I think the "debatable" part he's referring to is in using tables for forms. While the purist says no, I have seen some concession made for forms from more pragmatic developers. Hopefully, `display: table` will help with that in the future.

Comment: +1 @Shauna IE7 is basically dead, so the time to embrace display: table; is now! :)

Comment: @Shauna - `display:table` doesn't change anything because that's presentation and has nothing to do with document structure. The problem is using tables in HTML for layout which is also presentation but also non-semantic, inflexible, and slow in performance. Never use tables for layout and there's nothing debatable about it.

Comment: @Rob - That's my point - `display:table` to get the *look* that was previously achieved via tables. The reason people make exceptions to the "no tables for layout" rule is because of how tables lay forms out. The rise of `display:table` allows everyone to move away from the last place that tables are even considered for layout purposes, *because* `display:table` is entirely for presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't neccessarily need any `<div>`s, just make better use of the existing form elements;

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose Dates</legend>
        <input> To <input>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Status</legend>
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Pending</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Confirmed</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Canceled</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now, the real work lies in writing the css to style it to look like you want. I'd start with removing the border from the `<fieldset>` and float them next to each other.

```
fieldset {
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/ZqQRh/1/

(I have left out some of the essential details and attributes as the question is primarily about the structure)